# while using JsonRequestBehavior in web api giving error saying cannot convert to json.serializer

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'
```

code

```
public class PondController : ApiController
{
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
            {
                var pond = DB.Temperatures.OrderByDescending(x => x.WaterTemperature).FirstOrDefault();
                return Json(new { success = true, sensorsdata = new { id = pond.WaterTemperature, CurrentTime = pond.CreatedDate } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
        }
        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use code snippet from ASP.NET MVC in ASP.NET WebAPI controller. In WebAPI the results and methods have different signatures. Try following:

```
public JsonResult<object> Get()
{
    try
    {
        using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
        {
            var pond = DB.Temperatures.OrderByDescending(x => x.WaterTemperature).FirstOrDefault();
            return Json((object)new { success = true, sensorsdata = new { id = pond.WaterTemperature, CurrentTime = pond.CreatedDate } });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
    }
    return Json((object)new { success = false });
}
```